# Spring security custom authentication provider always resulted in bad client credentials

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, restful-authentication

I am implementing a custom authentication provider in spring security that authenticates user. Authentication server is in remote side (Restful service). everytime I called my service I encounterd with this error (this code reaches the

`return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, authentication.getCredentials().toString(), grantedAuthorities);`
 part )

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bad client credentials"}
```

here is my code:

### CustomAuthenticationProvider

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.createDefault());
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000)
            .setSocketTimeout(60 * 1000).build();
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(20);
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .build();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClientBuilder);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    UserInfoRequestBean userInfoRequestBean = new UserInfoRequestBean();

    String username = (String)authentication.getPrincipal();
    userInfoRequestBean.setUsername(username);
    userInfoRequestBean.setPassword((String)authentication.getCredentials());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<UserInfoRequestBean>(userInfoRequestBean, headers);

    try{                                
        ResponseBean<LoginResponseBean> responseBody = restTemplate.exchange(getLoginUrl(), HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseBean<LoginResponseBean>>() {}).getBody();
        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
        userDetails.setGender(responseBody.getResult().getGender());
        userDetails.setLastLoginDate(new Date());
        userDetails.setYaghutSessionId(responseBody.getResult().getSessionId());
        userDetails.setName(responseBody.getResult().getName());
        userDetails.setUsername(username);

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        // Granting authorization roles to user
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, authentication.getCredentials().toString(), grantedAuthorities);

    }catch (RestClientException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
        //TODO: implement this method
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

private String getLoginUrl(){
    //return restful service url
}

}
```

### Spring-security-config

```
<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />


<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>


<bean id="customProvider"
    class="com.adpdigital.idm.security.provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />

<authentication-manager id="customAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider ref="customProvider" />
</authentication-manager> 

<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="customAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing UserDetails simply pass the username, when returning UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. Below is the example -

```
return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, authentication.getCredentials().toString(), grantedAuthorities);
```